# Warning: pg_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

The following error is appearing in my code

Warning:  pg_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/funcoes.php on line 52

This is the code of the function:

```
function cadastrarFornecedor($nome){

    $qry = "INSERT INTO public.fornecedor (nome) VALUES ('".$nome."')";

    $result = pg_query($qry);

    if(pg_num_rows() > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part exactly in that error message is unclear?

Comment: Yes - the error does indeed appear. But what exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

`pg_num_rows` takes a result-set variable as an argument. The error is telling you that an argument is expected but none was provided.

See the unction signature: `int pg_num_rows ( resource $result )`

Where, $result:

> PostgreSQL query result resource, returned by pg_query(),
>   pg_query_params() or pg_execute() (among others)

So your code should pass the query result set to `pg_num_rows`, like the example below:

```
function cadastrarFornecedor($nome){
    $qry = "INSERT INTO public.fornecedor (nome) VALUES ('".$nome."')";
    $result = pg_query($qry);

    if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return 1;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php

(Note that `pg_num_rows` will return zero if you insert into a view with a `DO INSTEAD` trigger, a table with partitioning triggers/rules, etc.)

Comment: What about an explanation? How do we know what you've changed with the code. What you are doing here is encouraging someone to copy/paste your code into their codebase - this is not the right idea...

Comment: The method signature is the first thing I put...

Comment: Yes - but the **actual** issue here was that a parameter was missing. You do not mention this in your answer. If the OP managed to miss that point when writing their code, why do you think they will notice the difference with your suggestion?

Comment: @Lix his answer looks complete to me, why don't you edit it if you feel like its missing something?

Comment: @jenny - My aim here is to educate other members of the community. I could very easily go in and edit every post I don't think is quite right - but that will not help the OP of this answer to post better answers.

Comment: What I was aiming for here is the fact that not once was the phrase "you're missing a parameter" mentioned. If the OP missed that detail when writing their code, why would they suddenly notice it when reading an answer on [so]. It is always better to be explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: It might also be good to note here that the current vote on this answer is not mine. Newer users need guidance and encouragement. Established users need it too - but for them I find it's more effective to be a little harsher :P

Answer (score -2):

> Warning: pg_num_rows() **expects exactly 1 parameter**, 0 given in /var/www/funcoes.php on line 52

The error speaks for itself

```
function cadastrarFornecedor($nome){
  $qry = "INSERT INTO public.fornecedor (nome) VALUES ('" . $nome . "')";
  $result = pg_query($qry);

  if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      return 1;
  }
  else {
      return 0;
  }
}
```